# Change extension icon from Content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension that detects certain domains and it's supposed to change the icon, gray badge, red badge or green badge depending on the domain.

I'm trying to use from the conten script:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path : {
            "16": "icons/icon16.png",
            "19": "icons/icon19.png",
            "48": "icons/icon48.png"
        }
    });
```

The thing is, it says chrome.browserAction is undefined.

This is my manifest.json

```
    {
    "name": "CHANGE THIS : Extension boilerplate",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
    "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "options_page": "src/options_custom/index.html",
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
        "default_title": "page action demo",
        "default_popup": "src/page_action/page_action.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "css": [
                "src/inject/inject.css"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "/js/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "src/inject/inject.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["icons/stop.png"]

    }
```

I can get the initial icon to appear, but I can't change it.

Comment: You can't access `chrome.browserAction` from a content script. Use a background script and messaging.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310292/chrome-extension-dynamically-change-icon-without-clicking/47311213#47311213